# Iterate through structure elements of the same type

Tags: c

C beginner here, struggling to find a solution to this online.

I'm currently building a function to output structure data, but before outputting checks if data is present.

**This is my current solution:**

```
if (strcmp(P.strFullName.arcTitle, " ") != 0)
    printf("%s ", P.strFullName.arcTitle);

if (strcmp(P.strFullName.arcFirstName, " ") != 0)
    printf("%s ", P.strFullName.arcFirstName);

if (strcmp(P.strFullName.arcMiddleName, " ") != 0)
    printf("%s ", P.strFullName.arcMiddleName);

if (strcmp(P.strFullName.arcSurname, " ") != 0)
    printf("%s ", P.strFullName.arcSurname);        
printf("\n");
```

All structure elements here are strings, and I would ideally like to be able to loop through the 2 key lines with the if and printf function, simply changing what structure element the loop is looking at each increment.

Is there any way to simplify this?

Comment: Why not have an array of strings in the struct, and simply use a loop?

Comment: Can you please add the struct defenition?

Comment: [This Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784782/is-there-any-way-to-loop-through-a-struct-with-elements-of-different-types-in-c) will be helpful.

Comment: does arcMiddleName,arcTitle etc have same size ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating over same type struct members in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869776/iterating-over-same-type-struct-members-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

You can write a small function that holds the if condition and also prints.

```
void CheckAndPrint(char *str)
{
   if (strcmp(str, " ") != 0)
        printf("%s ", str); 
}
```

Then in the main code you can call it as,

```
CheckAndPrint(P.strFullName.arcTitle);
CheckAndPrint(P.strFullName.arcFirstName);
CheckAndPrint(P.strFullName.arcMiddleName);
CheckAndPrint(P.strFullName.arcSurname);
```

This has the advantage that maybe later if you want to add another check before printing, it will have to be done in only one place.

Answer (score 1):

If you really must "iterate", you can use the standard `offsetof` macro to calculate the offset of each member, and then access it through the address of the struct:

```
struct full_name {
  char const *arcTitle;
  char const *arcFirstName;
  char const *arcMiddleName;
  char const *arcSurname;
};

void print_full_name (struct full_name *fname) {
  size_t offest[] = {
    offsetof(struct full_name, arcTitle),
    offsetof(struct full_name, arcFirstName),
    offsetof(struct full_name, arcMiddleName),
    offsetof(struct full_name, arcSurname)
  };

  for (size_t idx = 0; idx < sizeof(offset)/sizeof(offset[0]); ++i) {
    char *mem_raw_ptr = (char*)fname + offset[idx];
    char const *str = *(char const **)mem_raw_ptr;

    if (strcmp(str, " ") != 0)
      printf("%s ", str); 
  }
}
```

Be certain that all members you "iterate" over have the same type! And remember that you calculate a pointer to that member, so pointers to pointers may need to be used, when appropriate (and possibly, heaven forbid, pointers to arrays).

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use assign different variable names to the same memory area. To treat it as if it has individual variable names, while at the same time have the ability to treat it as an array. To achieve that, we can use a union:

```
typedef struct
{
  const char* title; 
  const char* firstName;
  const char* middleName;
  const char* surname;
} arcStr;

typedef struct
{
  ...
  union
  {
    arcStr arc;
    const char* array[4];
  };
  ...
} some_struct;
```

Usage: `P.strFullName.arc.title`.

So quite similar to what you already had, but you can now loop over this data as well:

```
for(size_t i=0; i<4; i++)
{
  if (strcmp(P.strFullName.array[i], " ") != 0)
    printf("%s ", P.strFullName.array[i]);
}
```